# É possível criar uma classe dentro de uma lista?

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou montando uma lista que possui uma imagem e seto seu tamanho na mesma linha conforme o código abaixo.

```
<tr>
    <th>
       <img src="images/radio1.jpg" width="48px" , height="48px" />
    </th>
    <th>Tradição AM</th>
    <th>11.750.246/0001-05</th>
</tr>
```

Quero criar uma classe dentro de uma `<th>` para setar o `width` e `heigth` pela minha folha de css para facilitar o trabalho. Isso é possível? Se não, de que outra forma posso atingir um resultado parecido?

Comment: Sim você pode criar uma classe e depois editar os tamanhos, cores etc em seu CSS

Comment: mas onde? dentro da th? no inicio da tbody? tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sintaxe do seu HTML está errada:

```
                            essa vírgula não deveria existir
                                          ↓
<img src="images/radio1.jpg" width="48px" , height="48px" />
                                      ↑               ↑
                      esses valores devem ser numéricos, e não aceitam px
```

O correto seria:

```
<img src="images/radio1.jpg" width="48" height="48" />
```

Se você quer setar as dimensões da imagem via CSS, altere o elemento para:

```
<img src="images/radio1.jpg" />
```

E coloque no seu CSS:

```
th img{ /* seleciona img dentro do th */
   width: 48px;
   height: 48px
}
```

Você pode adicionar uma classe nas `th` também:

```
<tr>
    <th class="lista">
       <img src="images/radio1.jpg" width="48px" , height="48px" />
    </th>
    <th>Tradição AM</th>
    <th>11.750.246/0001-05</th>
</tr>
```

Aí muda o seletor também:

```
th.lista img{ /* seleciona img dentro do th */
   width: 48px;
   height: 48px
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
th.lista img{
   width: 48px;
   height: 48px
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th class="lista">
       <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" />
    </th>
    <th>Tradição AM</th>
    <th>11.750.246/0001-05</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: mas no caso dessa forma, sempre que houver uma imagem dentro de uma th ela ficara nesse tamanho certo? como eu poderia criar uma classe dentro dessa lista? vc pode adicionar isso na sua resposta?

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Atualizei a resposta. Veja se era isso. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um examplo abaixo.

Em seu arquivo.html coloque assim, lembrando que não é recomendado usar o style dentro do html, mas sim direto pelo css.

```
<style>
 .classth1{width:50%};
 .classth2{color:green};
 .classth3{color:blue};
<style>

<tr>
  <th class="classth1">
    <img src="images/radio1.jpg" width="48px" , height="48px" />
  </th>
  <th class="classth2">Tradição AM</th>
  <th class="classth3">11.750.246/0001-05</th>
</tr>
```